# Array to String with multiple languages

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have some data that is being fed into my form via php. I am then adding additional information to that and it is being sent out.  There is no telling how many rows will be in my table, and Values 1-3 is the additional information that I am adding to EACH row.

How I send the info:

```
if(isset($_POST['val1']))
    {
        echo "Submitting\n";
print_r($_POST);
        $variable = "val1=" . $_POST['val1'] . ",val2=" . $_POST['val2'] . ",val3=" . $_POST['val3'];
        // set post fields
        $post = [
        'submit' => 'true',
        'activity_name' => 'DataSend',
        'params'   => [
            'Data' => $variable
        ]
        ];
```

How I think I need to get it to go out as a string to the application (I realize there is a bunch of options here, I'm not sure how to get it to work) I need this to go out as a string, right now it is being received as an Array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendData() {
var inputs = document.getElementById(‘TableName’).getElementsByTagName('input'),
data = [],
name, val1[], val2[], val3[];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if ( inputs[i].type === 'submit') {
        continue;
    }

    var variable = ''; for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i<len,i++) { variable += 'val1' + i + '=' + val1[i] + ',val2' + i + '=' + val2[i] + ',val3' + i + '=' + val3[i] + ','; }

var array_objects = [
    {'name': 'val1';},
    {'name': 'val2';},
    {'name': 'val3';},
]
var array_to_join = [];

for (x = 0; x < array_objects.length;
     x++) {
_.map(array_objects[x], function(key, value) {
      array_to_join.push(key + '=' + value);
      });
}
document.body.innerHTML =
array_to_join.join(', ');
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Then again maybe i am over complicating this since they just want a string back and all I need to do is json.Stringify(data) or json.toJSON(data). I wouldn't even need to do all the looping because I would just be constructing a data model in JSON and passing that into the function? It would be a JSON object turned into a string, should get the job done right?

Comment: I think you've answered it yourself :)

Comment: Thanks @Stuart!  Working out the solution at this moment!